# Get Window.Opener handle for popups opened within from flash

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a webpage (popup) with flash content. When a user clicks a button inside the flash content, it opens up another browser popup window. Next, I need to close the window with flash content from the newly opened popup window through javascript.

The problem is that the `window.Opener` is null as the popup is invoked inside from flash content. Moreover we dont have access to flash (.FLA) file.

Please help me to get around this.

Comment: Are all these pages on the same domain?

Comment: Yes all web pages pages including popups are on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

With ExternalInterface, have your Flash code call openPopup() and closePopup() JS functions in the original window. These functions can keep track of the opener handle.

BTW, popup windows are bad. They are hard to work with, hated by users, and thwarted by browsers. If your client insists, then talk your client out of it. Use an Ajax dialog instead.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, BTW I don't have permission nor access to the .FLA file. So is there any other way to get around this?